# Code a small Python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to write a small dictionary in which there is an n number in the first line that represents the number of words in the dictionary. Each of the n next lines consists of two words indicating that the second word means the first word. The next line contains a sentence. A sentence consists of several words separated by space.

I tried to visualize the word salam in the output to the user when the user enters the Hello word.

The code I could write is this:

```
dic = {
         'Hello': 'Salam',
         'Goodbye': 'Khodafez',
         'Say': 'Goftan',
         'We': 'Ma',
         'You': 'Shoma'
      }

n = int(input())
usrinp = input()

for i in range(n):
    for i in dic:
        if usrinp in dic:
            print(i + ' ' + dic[i])
        else:
            usrinp = input()
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can I be able to display the output of the salam expression when the user enters the hello entry?
And so on for all the components of the dictionary

Comment: Alright I corrected your code in case you wanted exactly that. Even though you may prefer Austin's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read user input. Repeat for that many number of times - get items from dictionary using `get` attribute which handles `KeyError` itself:

```
dic = {'Hello': 'Salam', 'Goodbye': 'Khodafez', 'Say': 'Goftan', 'We': 'Ma', 'You': 'Shoma'}

n = int(input())
for _ in range(n):
    print(dic.get(input(), 'Wrong Input'))
```

**EDIT**:

```
dic = {'Hello': 'Salam', 'Goodbye': 'Khodafez', 'Say': 'Goftan', 'We': 'Ma', 'You': 'Shoma'}

n = int(input())
for _ in range(n):
    usrinp = input()
    print(dic.get(usrinp, usrinp))
```

Comment: How can I do when a user inputs a word that was not in the dictionary, instead of the same word that he entered in the output to him?

Comment: So basically you want to output what the user enters if the item is not in the dictionary?

Comment: If the dictionary that the user entered was not in the dictionary, he would display the same word that he entered.

Comment: Thank you for taking me to the time <3

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following example, maybe it can help:

```
dic = {
  'Hello': 'Salam', 
  'Goodbye': 'Khodafez', 
  'Say': 'Goftan', 
  'We': 'Ma', 
  'You': 'Shoma'
}

# Get the text, remove whitespaces and define
# it as title (to be exaclty equal to the dict)
text = input().strip().title()

# Convert the text into a list
text = text.split()

result = []

# Get the translation for each word
for t in text:
    if t in dic:
        result.append(dic[t])

# Join the list to print a string
print ' '.join(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly a corrected version of OP code, no more no less what you needed:

```
dic = {'Hello': 'Salam', 'Goodbye': 'Khodafez', 'Say': 'Goftan', 'We': 'Ma','You': 'Shoma'}
n = int(input())

for i in range(n):
    usrinp = input()
    while usrinp not in dic.keys():
        usrinp = input()
    print(str(i) + ' ' + str(dic[usrinp]))
```